# SQL order by day closest to now

Tags: sql

I got a infoscreen with users (employees) day of birth (birthday) and day of employment (anniversary day). The screen currently only shows employees who have birthday / anniversary within a month (from todays date). I need to order the employees so the ones who have birthday or anniversary closest to now, are shown first in the query.

I got this SQL going

```
SELECT users.*

FROM {prefix}usermeta as usermeta
JOIN {prefix}users as users ON users.ID = usermeta.user_id

WHERE 

(usermeta.meta_key = "foedselsdag" OR usermeta.meta_key = "jubilaeum")

   AND
( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "%format_date_string|Y|now%", " " , DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD( '1950-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL usermeta.meta_value SECOND ), "%m %d" ) ), "%Y %m %d" ) ) < %str_to_time|today+1month%
   AND
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "%format_date_string|Y|now%", " " , DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD( '1950-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL usermeta.meta_value SECOND ), "%m %d" ) ), "%Y %m %d" ) ) > %str_to_time|yesterday% )
   OR
( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "%format_date_string|Y|first day of next year%", " " , DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD( '1950-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL usermeta.meta_value SECOND ), "%m %d" ) ), "%Y %m %d" ) ) < %str_to_time|today+1month%
   AND
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "%format_date_string|Y|first day of next year%", " " , DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD( '1950-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL usermeta.meta_value SECOND ), "%m %d" ) ), "%Y %m %d" ) ) > %str_to_time|yesterday% )
```

I tried the following

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY
  ABS(
    DATEDIFF(
      day,
      DATEADD(DATEDIFF('fodselsdag' OR 'jubilaum', GETDATE()), 'fodselsdag' OR 'jubilaum'),
      GETDATE()
    )
  )
```

Comment: What issue(s) did you have with what you tried?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used above.)

Answer (score 0):

You woukd use a CASE WHEn to detemine which is ealier

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN 
ABS(DATEDIFF(day, fodselsdag,  GETDATE())) <= ABS(DATEDIFF(day, jubilaum,  GETDATE()))
THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(day, fodselsdag,  GETDATE()))
ELSE ABS(DATEDIFF(day, jubilaum,  GETDATE()))
END
```